# jQuery / ASP - Upload progress using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, progress-bar

I'm wondering if my solution to receiving progress indication of an upload would work, and if it's possible, am I going about it the right way? It doesn't have to be really accurate, I just want a little more than a spinning, animated icon.

1) On upload form page ////////

```
Submit upload form & files to processing page.
```

2) On processing page /////////

```
For Each file In myFileArray Then
   ' Save the file
   ' Add 1 to a cookie called progressReport
Next
```

3) On upload form page ///////

```
checkTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
    var cookieContents = $.cookie('progressReport');
    if (cookieContents != "")
    $('#uploadProgress').html(cookieContents + ' files uploaded');
}, 2000);
```

**---- UPDATE ----**

Thanks to a below answer, I cannot accomplish this because the cookie would not get written until the page finished processing - meaning the user wouldn't get any feedback until it had finished. Useless!

I've changed my plan. This suits my application, probably not to some.

1) Make AJAX call to server page that creates a unique ID and a folder named, 'unique ID'. When done, send ID back as response, add unique ID to hidden input in upload form.

2) User submits file(s), check ID is present in hidden input, then post to a hidden iFrame. On submission, make an AJAX call to another server page every 1-5 seconds, checking how many files are in that folder, send quantity back as response, update progress panel.

Comment: How can this possibly be related to both asp.net _and_ asp-classic?

Comment: @cdeszaq - Because you can save a file and write a cookie in asp.net, so somebody that writes asp.net, may know if this would work and should understand the above code example. Stop being such a loser!!

Comment: Can't believe I just got down-voted because of bad tag. Why don't you use your special powers and edit the question, removing the tag!

Comment: I didn't remove the tag because I was unsure which technology you were targeting, hence, the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because this:

```
For Each file In myFileArray Then
   ' Save the file
   ' Add 1 to a cookie called progressReport
Next
```

Will not write the cookie to the browser until all the files are finished.

You need to devise a way to start uploading these files one by one **from the client side**. Your processing page receives only one file; increments the value in the cookie and finishes the response. In other words, your processing page ends up being called n times for n files. Your javascript code keeps reading the cookie every 2 seconds and displaying the value that was updated by the last response.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but using a cookie is a strange way of doing it. If the progress is stored on the server side then you should just update the client through an ajax request. It's definitely possible to use a cookie, but it seems unnecessary. If you want the client to be updated of when a certain request, for example, has finished stage one, then two, until it finally finishes, then you should probably look into "Long polling" as an alternative. Or certain push systems.

For uploading files, you'll be able to find a few examples of how they show progress. And if you're up to, HTML5 has revised [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) to make it easier to manage things like upload progress.